# What's the best way to extend the scope of a variable for use in a lambda in c++?

Tags: c++

I have class:

```
class MyFunctionRunner{
  public:
      static callFunc(){
         func_(); //Calls the function that's set
      }
      static setFunc(std::function<void()> func){
         func_ = func; //Sets a function
      }
 private:
     static std::function<void()> func_;
 }
```

And a function:

```
void MyFunc(const std::string& a,const std::string& b){
   MyClass myObj{};

   MyFunctionRunner::setFunc(
     [&myObj](){
        myObj.setA(a); 
        myObj.setB(b);
   }); //Passes in a lambda function as a parameter that captures `myObj` as reference. 
 }
```

In my main, I have:

```
myFunc("a","b");
MyFunctionRunner::callFunc();
```

This compiles fine but hits a runtime error of "stack-use-after-return" because I guess it's by the time I run the function, `myObj` is out of scope? What can I do to extend the scope/lifetime of `myObj` reference ? Assume that `MyClass`'s implementation (out of my control) has prevented copy constructor ("copy constructor is implicitly deleted...")

Comment: Capture by value instead of by reference?

Comment: That would be very expensive speed wise, no ? Or is it only expensive memory wise? Actually imagine MyClass has prevented copy constructor.

Comment: `a` and `b` are not captured in the sample, doesn't it trigger compile error for you as well?

Comment: @user1008636 Can you move it into the lambda?

Comment: @NathanOliver you mean have the lambda function itself create the object ?

Comment: @user1008636 No, a move operation: `MyClass myObj{}; setFunc([myObj = std::move(myObj)]() {...});`

Comment: Ah ok, just to be sure, that'll make `myObj` not safe to use again later in `MyFunc`, right?

Comment: @NathanOliver nope, the author of MyClass has prevented move operations on it too: `MyClass(MyClass&&) = delete`

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend the scope of the `myObj` variable without moving it into global/static memory.  But what you can do instead is create the `MyClass` object in dynamic memory and change `myObj` to be a *pointer* to that object, and then you can capture a *copy* of that pointer in the lambda, eg:

```
void MyFunc(const std::string& a,const std::string& b){
   MyClass *myObj = new MyClass;

   MyFunctionRunner::setFunc(
     [myObj](){
        myObj->setA(a); 
        myObj->setB(b);
        delete myObj;
   });
}
```

In which case, you should consider using a smart pointer for safer memory management, eg:

```
void MyFunc(const std::string& a,const std::string& b){
   auto myObj = std::make_shared<MyClass>();

   MyFunctionRunner::setFunc(
     [myObj](){
        myObj->setA(a); 
        myObj->setB(b);
   });
}
```

Comment: What makes having a shared_ptr to MyClass be part of 'dynamic memory'. ?

Comment: `myObj` itself is not in dynamic memory.  But it is holding a pointer to an object that is in dynamic memory.  The code is capturing a *copy* of `myObj`, and thus a copy of the pointer, into the lambda. The actual object being pointed at doesn't move.

Comment: @user1008636: `std::make_shared` creates an object in dynamic memory